# Is it true that every coset of $\Bbb{R/Q}$ (group and normal subgroup) is represented by an irrational number (aside from 0)?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

This question stems from the study of Vitali sets. Is it true that every coset of $\Bbb{R/Q}$ (group and normal subgroup) is represented by an irrational number ? $\Bbb{I}$ being the set of irrational numbers. My intuition says yes. If we take two distinct cosets of $\Bbb{R/Q}$, and we take the difference between two representatives of the cosets (so any two elements from $\Bbb{Q}$), we get an irrational number by construction. In particular, if we take the same rational number for both the cosets (represented by, let's say, $r_1$ and $r_2$ both nonzero), then their difference (which is $r_1-r_2$) must be irrational, so at least one of them has to be irrational. Assuming that the other one is in fact rational (let's say $r_1$), we can construction two other distinct r's (let's say $r_3$ and $r_4$) such that one of them is rational (let's say $r_3$). But then  $r_1-r_3$ is rational and we get a contradiction, proving that r must be irrational.

The deduction seems a bit sloppy to me, so I'm sure I made some mistakes, but I'd like to know whether the question is true or false and why it is so, thanks.

Comment: Note that the only difference between those is literally $\Bbb Q$ (as an element!) itself.

Comment: Is it meaningful to consider the quotient (quotient... ring? topological space?) of $\mathbb{I}/\mathbb{Q}$ when $\mathbb{Q}\cap\mathbb{I}=\emptyset$?

Comment: You're right, probably my question is (to say the least) ill-posed. What I was trying to say is that every coset of $\Bbb{R/Q}$ (group and normal subgroup) is represented by an irrational number. Don't know the formal way to phrase it though.

Comment: The coset $\Bbb Q$ obviously don't have an irrational representative

Comment: @jjagmath And aside from $\Bbb{0}$? I mean, what's wrong in my deduction?

Comment: For a nonzero coset, not only **is there** an irrational representative, but indeed **every** representative is irrational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you have a group $G$, and a normal subgroup $N$, for any $h\in N$, the coset $hN=N$.  So any coset other than $N$ is represented by an $h$ such that $h\not\in N$.

So in this case, with $\Bbb Q\triangleleft \Bbb R$, in $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$ to get a coset other than $\Bbb Q$ (which is the coset of $0$, since $0\in\Bbb Q$), you need to take an irrational.

Comment: Crystal clear, thanks. It's way cleaner than mine, but is mine correct?

Comment: Honestly,  you lost me right away,  when you said take two different coset representatives, take their difference, and then  you said,  "so any two elements of $\Bbb Q$"...  I couldn't follow.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase it, thanks